# Keycloak Quarkus cluster replication

Tags: keycloak

Good morning,

we have a use case that involves 2 different Windows environments, in which the applications should authz against a keycloak server.

The first environment contains the leading AD, which is replicated once a day into the second environment, since the second environment must not query the AD of the first one. This is a firewalling policy.

Now our thought is to use keycloak as a “bridge” between the two environments, having a keycloak server in the first environment reading the AD with user federation turned on.
In the second environment the keycloak server somehow replicates with the first one, in the best case via HTTPS (which could pass the firewall) so the applications and users in the second environment can authz with the same credentials as in the first environment.

Is there a way to achieve this or something similar?

thx in advance

Frank